# AR Core plane detection. I want smaller plane

Tags: unity-game-engine, mobile, augmented-reality, arcore, ar-foundation

I'm creating Wi-Fi heat map using arcore.
But arcore automatically merge the detected plane into one large plane.

I am changing the color of the plane created by the Foreach statement collectively, so to function properly as a heat map, I want the plane to be recognized as being cut off in an appropriate size instead of being united as one.
Or if I can color the color of one plane with gradation according to the conditions rather than one color, the corresponding method would be good.
Can you recommend a better way to implement the two solutions? And I also want to know how.